# MPAndroidChart insert Y axis listArray variable or dynamic params

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I would like to introduce variable or dinamic parameter into Y axis (`MPAndroidChart`). The params comes from remote server, and they are not fix params since they are "temperature and Humidity" catched from a sensor in real time, then It is allocated in Mysql and from my APP make a chart after getting this data.

I would like to have any help on how to make it. I have my code like this:

For params (humidity and temperature) in method `CapatarParametros()` using loopj to connect to server and getting the data:

```
List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray cast = jsonobject.getJSONArray("result");
for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject parametrosdht11 = cast.getJSONObject(i);
    String temperatura = parametrosdht11.getString("temperatura");
    String humedad = parametrosdht11.getString("humedad");
    allNames.add(temperatura);
    allNames.add(humedad);
```

This code give me temperature and humedity. Now I need to take these parameters and add to the y axis (per exemple "temperature" ) in Oncreate :

```
 LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
 ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DatosSensor extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    private static final String SENSORS_URL = "http://.....";

    // Progress Dialog Object
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    // Error Msg TextView Object
    TextView errorMsg;
    // Email Edit View Object

    private String temeperatura;

    ArrayList<Entry> temperature = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<>();

    LineChart mChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_datos_sensor);
        String idObjeto = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("IdentidadEnviada");

        CaptarParametros(idObjeto);

        mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        // no description text
        mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");

        // enable touch gestures
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

        mChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);

        // enable scaling and dragging
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mChart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);

        // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
        mChart.setPinchZoom(true);

        // set an alternative background color
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        mChart.animateX(2500);

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setTextSize(11f);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setAxisMaxValue(100f);
        xAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);

        //modify leftYaxis range similarly others
        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setTextColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(100f);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);


        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        rightAxis.setAxisMaxValue(100f);
        rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
        rightAxis.setGranularityEnabled(false);


        // add data
        setData();
    }


    private void CaptarParametros(String idObjeto) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put(UtilitiesGlobal.SENSOR_ID, idObjeto);

        RequestHandle post = client.post(this, SENSORS_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                JSONObject jsonobject = null;
                JSONObject dht11JSONbject = null;
                JSONArray dht11JSONarray = null;


                try {

                    jsonobject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    //dht11JSONbject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("result");


                    List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray cast = jsonobject.getJSONArray("result");
                    for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject parametrosdht11 = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                        String temperatura = parametrosdht11.getString("temperatura");
                        String humedad = parametrosdht11.getString("humedad");
                        temperature.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(i),Float.valueOf(temperatura)));
                        yVals2.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(i),Float.valueOf(humedad)));

                        //rrefresh
                        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + usuarioiJSONbject);
                        Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " +"temperatura: "+ temperatura +" humedad: " +humedad);
                    }

    private void setData() {
//data set represents a lin
        LineDataSet set1, set2;

        // create a dataset and give it a type
        //modifications with colour and stuf
        set1 = new LineDataSet(temperature, "Temperatur");
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set1.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        set1.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setLineWidth(2f);
        set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
        set1.setFillAlpha(65);
        set1.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);


        // similar above
        set2 = new LineDataSet(yVals2, "Humidity");
        set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
        set2.setColor(Color.RED);
        set2.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        set2.setLineWidth(2f);
        set2.setCircleRadius(1f);
        set2.setFillAlpha(65);
        set2.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        set2.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        set2.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
        //set2.setFillFormatter(new MyFillFormatter(900f));

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets
        dataSets.add(set2);

        // create a data object with the datasets
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setValueTextSize(9f);

        // set data
        Log.i("Lists Sizedata",temperature.size() + " and " + yVals2.size());
        mChart.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Create two activities. One for Chart, other one interface for Asyncronics.
DataSensor.java

```
public class DatosSensor extends AppCompatActivity implements onLoopjTaskFinished {

    private onLoopjTaskFinished loopjListener;

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    TextView errorMsg;
    private String temeperatura;

    ArrayList<Entry> entries;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_datos_sensor);

        String idObjeto = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("IdentidadEnviada");

        CaptarParametros(idObjeto);

        LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        entries = new ArrayList<>();
        //entries.add(new Entry(60f, 0));
        //entries.add(new Entry(6f, 1));
        //entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
        //entries.add(new Entry(2f, 3));
        //entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));
        //entries.add(new Entry(60f, 5));

        Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onCreate: entries size = " + entries.size());

        LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();


        LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);
        dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS); //
        dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
        dataset.setDrawFilled(true);


        lineChart.setData(data);
        lineChart.animateY(5000);


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idObjeto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        agregarToolbar();

    @Override
    public void onLoopjFinishedSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray cast = null;
        try {
            cast = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cast.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject parametrosdht11 = null;
            String temperatura = null;
            String humedad = null;
            try {
                parametrosdht11 = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                temperatura = parametrosdht11.getString("temperatura");
                humedad = parametrosdht11.getString("humedad");
                allNames.add(temperatura);
                allNames.add(humedad);

                float tempFloat = Float.parseFloat(temperatura);
                entries.add(new Entry(tempFloat, i));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + usuarioiJSONbject);
            Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + "temperatura: " + temperatura + " humedad: " + humedad);
        }
    }

Interface (onLoopjTaskFinished)

    public interface onLoopjTaskFinished {
    void onLoopjFinishedSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject);
    void onLoopjFinishedFailure(int statusCode);

}
```

I took out some code that it is not relevant, just to simplify.

Comment: Nobody in Stackoverflow sent an answer. so another tow people gave me a solution out of web. Then I wrote it in order other people could take it when they had same problem like me, but because it was not my own solution, but it was from third sides, I wrote the link and name of people who gave me the solution,. This is known as "to be educated" and not spam, since the system have not another way to solve this situation.